# How to deal with: UIActionSheet deprecated (iOS8) X UIAlertController not supported (iOS7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, ios8

The UIActionSheet is deprecated on iOS 7 and the docs suggest to use UIAlertController however UIAlertController is not supported on iOS7 :P

My code will run if I do use the UIActionSheet in iOS8, there's a warning :P but it runs...

I wondering to know if is there another alternative instead of just leaving the deprecated code and make sure that it works for both iOS (7/8).

tkx

Comment: If your Deployment Target is iOS 7 then you should not get any warning for using `UIActionSheet`.

Comment: Yeah, but the "Deployment target" is already set to 7.0.

Comment: If it was, you wouldn't get a deprecation warning. Make sure it's set for the target. Perhaps the target setting is overriding the project setting.

Answer (score 2):

If you are writing shared code that can be used on both iOS 7 as well as an iOS 8 extension - where the UIAlertView/UIActionSheet APIs are restricted - have a look at [JVAlertController](http://www.github.com/jverdi/JVAlertController).

It's an open-source back-port UIAlertController to iOS 7 that I created to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

Like @rmaddy pointed out you should set your deployment target to iOS 7 and use UIActionSheet. That way you will not get any warnings and your code runs on both iOS 7/8!